# Returning values from elixir functions inside modules

Tags: recursion, elixir, variable-assignment

This is the method that processes an input string

```
def process(input) do
    list=String.split(input, "\n")

    f3=fn(a) ->
            String.split(a," ")
    end

    list=Enum.map(list, f3)

    func3=fn(n) ->
            length(n)==3
    end

    func2=fn(n) ->
            length(n)<=2
    end

    system=for x <-list, func3.(x), do: x

    input=for y <- list, func2.(y), do: y

    input=Enum.slice(input,0..length(input)-2)

    output=""

    output(input,output, system)
  end
```

This is the output function that uses recursion to edit a string and eventually return its value

```
def output(input, output, system) do
    cond do
      length(input)==0 ->
        output
      true ->
        [thing|tail]=input

        if length(thing)==2 do
          output=output<>"From "<>Enum.at(thing, 0)<>" to "<>Enum.at(thing,1)<>" is "<>Integer.to_string(calculate(thing, system))<>"km\n"
          output(tail, output, system)
        end

        if length(thing)==1 do
          if Enum.at(thing,0)=="Sun" do
                  output=output<>"Sun orbits"
                  output(tail, output, system)
          else
                  output=output<>orbits(thing, system)<>" Sun"
                  output(tail, output, system)
          end
        end

        output(tail, output, system)
    end
  end
```

As you can see when the input is an empty list it should return the output string. Using inspect shows that the output string does indeed have the correct value. Yet when the function is called in process(), it only returns the empty string, or nil.

Any help is appreciated, I am new to elixir so apologies if my code is a bit messy.

Comment: Variables/returns in Elixir work differently. When you assign a variable it's only available in the block where you assigned it. Your `output =` and recursive calls inside your `if` blocks are going to perform the work, but you just throw out the result, and your function is ultimately going to return the result of the recursive call at the bottom of your function.

Comment: I think it might be easier for us to wrap our heads around what you're trying to do if you could simply show the sample input along with the expected output.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

This could be a case where using pattern matching in the function head will let you avoid essentially all of the conditionals.  You could break this down as:

```elixir
def output([], message, _) do
  message
end

def output([[from, to] | tail], message, system) do
  distance = Integer.to_string(calculate(thing, system))
  new_message = "#{message}From #{from} to #{to} is #{distance} km\n"
  output(tail, new_message, system)
end

def output([["Sun"] | tail], message, system) do
  output(tail, "Sun orbits #{message}", system)
end

def output([[thing] | tail], message, system) do
  new_message = "#{message}#{orbits([thing], system)} Sun"
  output(tail, new_message, system)
end
```

This gets around some of the difficulties highlighted in the comments: reassigning `output` inside a block doesn't have an effect, and there aren't non-local returns so after an `if ... end` block completes and goes on to the next conditional, its result is lost.  This will also trap some incorrect inputs, and your process will exit with a pattern-match error if an empty or 3-element list winds up in the input list.

I've renamed the `output` parameter to the `output` function to `message`.  This isn't required – the code will work fine whether or not you change it – but I found it a little confusing reading through the function whether `output` is a function call or a variable.

Comment: Reading this function again, you also might consider skipping the recursive case and writing a function to produce an output message for a single input, then calling `Enum.map/2` to call it for every item in the list, then `Enum.join/2` to reduce a list of strings to a single string.